# Multiple One-To-One with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Basically I have situation where I have two different tables that I would like to link them with another one. Similar to situation when you have `User` and `Account` tables and you want them linked to `Settings` table, cause the `Settings` table could store settings either for a `User` or for an `Account`. Maybe it's not the best design, but that's what I'm stack with and have to implement  with Hibernate. I have seen many example of One-To-One, but it is possible something like this?

```
Table1 
  [id..]

         -> Table3
             [id...]
Table2
  [id...]
```

I would use id property to link `Table 1` with `Table3`, and also `Table2` with `Table3`. Could someone please provide an example implementation for this scenario ?

Comment: in your example, table1 is User, table3 is Setting, and table2 is Account?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: and there will be **only one** setting for an account or an user?

Comment: Yes, that's why I need one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can use this jpa mapping for your design:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Setting setting;

    // getters/setters, etc.

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "account")
    private Setting setting;

    // getters/setters, etc.
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "setting")
public class Setting {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // getters/setters, etc.

}
```

Comment: Not sure why, it works fine with one OneToOne, declared in Settings, but if I try adding another Spring breaks at boot, it doesn't say anything meaningful. Are you sure this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your need in this way:

1) The User table:

```
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "settingColumnName")
    private Settings setting;
}
```

2) The Account table:

```
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "settingColumnName")
    private Settings setting;
}
```

2) The Settings table:

```
@Table(name = "Settings")
public class Settings{
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "userColumnName")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountColumnName")
    private Account account;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, it works fine with one OneToOne, declared in Settings, but if I try adding another Spring breaks at boot, it doesn't say anything meaningful. Are you sure this works?

Comment: There's no limit on how many OneToOne you can add in class declaration, that's not the problem

Comment: Not sure why then, If I remove either User or Account declaration, it works, but not combined. I get javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: I found the issue, turns out in the settings model I had @JoinColumn(name = "id") for both relationships, which caused the issue, that's really weird, why it can't use the same column name in different tables...I guess I'll have to change colon name in one of the tables.

Comment: But doesn't make sense, why Account and User tables shouldn't have the same column names?